# ChartJS show jittering on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using chartJS

[image]

---

## Try#1

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(configs.selectorId).getContext('2d');
// chart.destroy();
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

---

## Try#2

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(configs.selectorId).getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
chart.update();
```

---

## Try#3

```
var ctx = document.getElementById(configs.selectorId).getContext('2d');
window[configs.selectorId] = new Chart(ctx, options);
window[configs.selectorId].update();
```

---

## Try#4

```
if(window[configs.selectorId] && window[configs.selectorId] !== null){
    window[configs.selectorId] = []
}

var ctx = document.getElementById(configs.selectorId).getContext('2d');
window[configs.selectorId] = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

---

## Try#6

```
if(window[configs.selectorId] && window[configs.selectorId] !== null){

    // console.log(window[configs.selectorId]);
    delete window[configs.selectorId];
}

console.log(window);

var ctx = document.getElementById(configs.selectorId).getContext('2d');
window[configs.selectorId] = new Chart(ctx, options);
window[configs.selectorId].update();
```

---

## Try#6

```
$('canvas').html("");

before call my chart
```

---

Please advise on how to do that.

I reproduce it here : http://bheng-charts-demo.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Suggestion create a fiddle and reduce the amount of code we have to read. its hard to tell exactly what is happening in the gif. your trys are not where the issue is, in saying that its no clear if you are trying to update the graph or just stop some sort of jitter

Comment: @Seabizkit : I deployed the project to heroku : http://bheng-charts-demo.herokuapp.com/, I will also attach my source code as .zip file in the poset, it is only 2 MBs.

Comment: you should try: `var chartX = window[configs.selectorId]; chartX.Data = "newdata"; chartX.update();` where newdata is proper data and all other options on chartX are set appropriately . that should work, im using update in my code base, but i dont change the interval, but in theory should work.

Comment: What u did is amazing and help me fix the interval change on the drop down menu. I’ll still have issues when I click on the carousel controller <,> . I removed the canvas and repaint it back. Should I not do that ? Should reproduce on my demo link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are using `new Chart()` constructor, accoding to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html) `destroy` method should be called before the canvas is reused for a new chart.

In your case it should work as follows

```
if(window[configs.selectorId] && window[configs.selectorId] !== null){

    if (typeof window[configs.selectorId].destroy === 'function') {
        window[configs.selectorId].destroy();
    }
    delete window[configs.selectorId];
}
```

Here is a snippet I've created on the basis of your code:
https://codepen.io/sergey_mell/pen/qBdBVpe
I've just changed your random data API to locally random generated data

Please, let me know if my answer is not clear enough or you need some additional information

Comment: I tried your code, my charts is not loadin : https://i.imgur.com/MIZQuCY.png

Comment: Have you see the file that I have in my repo. I made my repo public. Project is less than 3 MBs.

Comment: Yeah, but I used just markup with js. Are there any console errors? Because I've checked the implementation in my snippet (https://codepen.io/sergey_mell/pen/qBdBVpe) and it worker

Comment: I'm available for some chatting now, so we could figure out the solution

Comment: So, it seems that we have some js error in your version of the code. Did you add the check for destroy in correct place? Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Yep. Confirm. working. Sorry, it was my fault. I copied 2 lines from your codes.

Comment: All good now, you're my true hero man. Been stuck on it for 2 weeks.

Comment: When I click on the carousel, I also see flickering, but it was because I remove DOM and add back the DOM , and rendering.

Comment: Do you have suggestion for to avoid that bad glicth looking ?

Comment: Let me check. I didn't review the carousel flow

Comment: It is not reproducable on your codepen. I tried ‍♂️. I can see it very obvious on my screen locally. What is your suggestion for me ?

Comment: Beside these 5 lines, did you add anything else to my codes ? 

https://i.imgur.com/UqkEq5k.png

Comment: That might be the reason, your codepen is not showing any sign of issue.

Comment: Can you see what I mean ? or NO ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207364/discussion-between-sergey-mell-and-kyo).